# rotate an Ellipse2D object

Tags: java, user-interface, keyboard, shapes

I'm trying to rotate one whole Ellipse2D object based on user key input. If the user presses the right key, rotate right and left key means rotate left. The rotAngle is set to 25. I made a separate drawRotEllipse because otherwise it would have always drawn the original one. I think my confusion is happening with the Graphics and Shapes Objects. Tried the AffineTransform business but that didn't work out either. I just want it to rotate about the center. Thanks for any help!

```
class Canvas extends JPanel implements java.io.Serializable{
        int x1 = (int) (this.getWidth()/2)+100;
        int y1 = (int) (this.getHeight()/2)+20;
        int x2 = (int) this.getWidth()+100;
        int y2 = (int) this.getHeight()+200;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            drawEllipse(g);
        }

        public void drawEllipse (Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            myShape = new Ellipse2D.Double(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            g2d.draw(myShape);
            this.repaint();
        }

        public void drawRotEllipse (Graphics g){
            g2d.draw(myShape);
            this.repaint();
        }
    }


 private void jPanel1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        if (evt.getKeyCode()==39){
            g2d.rotate(Math.toDegrees(rotAngle));
            myCanvas.drawRotEllipse(g2d);
        }
        else if (evt.getKeyCode()==37){
            g2d.rotate(Math.toDegrees(-rotAngle));
            myCanvas.drawRotEllipse(g2d);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (evt.getKeyCode()==39)
```

Don't use magic numbers. People don't know that means by just looking at the code.

Instead use variable provided by the API:

```
if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
```

You KeyEvent code should not do the actual painting. All the code should do is set the "degrees" property of your class. The `setDegrees(...)` method will then be responsible for invoking repaint(). Now whenever the component is repainted the shape will be painted at its current degrees of rotation.

Here is an example that uses a JSlider to change the rotation degrees of the class.

It rotates an image. You should be able to change the code rotation the image to just draw your shape:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Rotation2 extends JPanel
{
    BufferedImage image;
    int degrees;
    int point = 250;

    public Rotation2(BufferedImage image)
    {
        this.image = image;
        setDegrees( 0 );
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(600, 600) );
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        double radians = Math.toRadians( degrees );
        g2.translate(point, point);
        g2.rotate(radians);
        g2.translate(-image.getWidth(this) / 2, -image.getHeight(this) / 2);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        g2.dispose();

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(point - 5, point - 5, 10, 10);
    }

    public void setDegrees(int degrees)
    {
        this.degrees = degrees;
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
//                  String path = "mong.jpg";
                    String path = "dukewavered.gif";
                    ClassLoader cl = Rotation2.class.getClassLoader();
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(cl.getResourceAsStream(path));
                    final Rotation2 r = new Rotation2(bi);

                    final JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 360, 0);
                    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
                    {
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
                        {
                            int value = slider.getValue();
                            r.setDegrees( value );
                        }
                    });

                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.add(new JScrollPane(r));
                    f.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    f.pack();
                    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Netbeans gui builder so some of the code is already generated for me. Your answer is completely different from my code and is suddenly using files and Image. I'm not using a Jslider.

Comment: I already stated the code was different. The point of the code was to show you the concept of `setting the degrees` and using that property in the painting method. Whether you use the slider to set the degress or a button to set the degrees is irrelevant. The concept is the same. I'm not going to write the code for you. Learn from the concept presented here and modify your code.  Start with the code here and make simple change to rotate a Shape. Then replace the slider with buttons.